# JSONSchema having different oneOf values for each entry in an array

Tags: typescript, jsonschema

I have the following schema. StaticListDropdown is a list which will be the same for every row of the array

DynamicListPerArrayEntry is a list of is a list that I need populating using the selected value of staticListDropdown as a key. When StaticListDropdown selected value is changed the items in DynamicListPerArrayEntry should be repopulated

I can't get the DynamicListPerArrayEntry to populate correctly

```
    const DynamicListPerArrayEntry = [{ title: "None", const: null }].concat(map(bars[bar], (bar, barId) => {
        return {
            title: bar.name,
            const: barId
        }
    }));

    const staticListDropdown = [{ title: "None", const: null }].concat(map(props.properties, (prop1, prope1Id) => {
        return {
            title: prop1.name,
            const: prope1Id
        }
    }));

    const exampleSchema : JSONSchema7 = {
        definitions: {
            foo: {
                title: "Foo",
                type: "object",
                properties: {
                    property1: {
                        type: "string",
                        title: "Property1",
                        oneOf: staticListDropdown,
                        },
                    bar: {
                        type: "string",
                        title: "Bar",
                        oneOf: DynamicListPerArrayEntry,
                        },
                    }
                },
            },
            properties: {
                foo: {
                  type: "array",
                  items: {
                    $ref: "#/definitions/foo"
                }
            },
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe this question needs some more clarification but for array tuple validation this link should help: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array.html#id7

Comment: @Clemens I can't see how to use Tuple validation for this issue. I have updated the question to give more clarification of the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with TypeScript, but shouldn't your JSON schema be more like this? I just put it in an editor and tried to clean up the mess a little bit:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "description": "JSON schema generated with JSONBuddy https://www.json-buddy.com",
  "title": "",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "foo": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/foo"
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "foo": {
      "title": "Foo",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "property1": {
          "type": "string",
          "title": "Property1",
          "oneOf": [ { "title": "None", "const": null } ]
        },
        "bar": {
          "type": "string",
          "title": "Bar",
          "oneOf": [ { "title": "None", "const": null } ]
        }
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

Please note, I replaced the `oneOf` values with actual arrays to make it working in the dev environment.

Comment: well yeah that looks cleaner, however it still needs to solve the issue that I want the contents described in the oneOf of bar to be different for every row, and how can we use use property1 to find the contents

Comment: You need to dynamically update your JSON schema to reflect this as you already tried in your original question. JSON schema itself can't do this for you. It doesn't work when you update your code with the clean schema? I am sorry, I don't know TypeScript in detail to help you more in this regard.

Comment: The problem is you only make one schema for an array, so you can specify a oneOf for a column, but you can't specify a aoneOf for each row in that column

Comment: Instead of a oneOf, isn't it sufficient to use an enum at the bar (dynamic) and property1 (static) definitions?

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding your solution properly (do you have an example) but I dont see how using an enum will load different values into bar for each row based on a search from the property1 schema. Im starting to think this cant be done using jsonschema